# How to get the data that has all relation datas specified

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building app with laravel.

What I want to do is to get users data with all qualifications specified in the search condition, and display the users list.

This is my model structure.

User:

```
id  name
1   John
2   Jack
```

Qualification:

```
id   name
11   A
12   B
13   C
```

Qualification_User:

```
qualification_id   user_id
11                 1
11                 2
12                 2
13                 2
```

If Setting a search condition "Qualification 11,12,13",

John has only 11  -> not listed.

Jack has all of the qualifications -> listed

I would like to implement this with a laravel query builder, Is there any way?

User.php

```
public function qualifications()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Qualification');
}
```

Controller

```
$query = App\User::query();
// other condition
// ....

// the case listed if one condition is matched
// but, this is not what I want to do
$query->whereHas(
    'qualifications',
    function ($query) use ($conditions) { //$conditions = [11,12,13]
      $query->whereIn('qualifications.id', $qualifications);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Can you show us your Query ?

Comment: @Saromase Thanks for replying.I've updated my post. the code is not what i want to do.sorry for my poor english

Comment: Your query return something or you have an error ? 
No problem i'm not the best in English too @Yoshihide

Comment: @Saromase With this code, users like having only qualification 11 are listed. What I'd like to do is to list only the users who has all the qualifications 11, 12, 13.

Comment: With this code, users that has one of these qualifications are listed. Query says that return me users that has a qualification that is either 11,12, or 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your User model:

```
public function qualifications()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Qualification::class,
        'qualification_user',
        'user_id',
        'qualification_id'
    );
}
```

Then in the controller, assuming you got qualification ids as an array:

```
$query = User::query();
foreach($qualificationIds as $id) {
    $query->whereHas('qualifications', function ($q) use ($id) {
        $q->where('id', $id);
    });
}
$query->get();
```